# I'm trying to show some divs on specific link click

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

My task for this evening is to show and hide a div (eventually two divs or more actually) when a link from the main nav is clicked. This will then hide divs when they click on another part of the main navigation.

**DONE**

Thanks go to everyone especially..Matchu....

the code is now as below and works....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tagcloud").hide();
            blogLink = $("ul.mainnav li.blog a").click(function () {    
            $("#tagcloud").show();});$("ul.mainnav li a").not       (blogLink).click(function () {    
            $("#tagcloud").hide();});      

            });
</script>
```

If anyone can see any possible problems with this, using it at www.alwaystwisted.com/index.html please let me know....

Also, have just ordered JQuery 1.3 book....so hopefully get my head around it a bit or a lot better....

regards

Sty

Comment: Played around with the page you gave me, try the code in my answer down there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated a THIRD time for the newest upload!**

Playing around with the page you gave me, here's what I could make work in the Firebug console, before you switched tagcloud to a class:

```
blogLink = $("ul.mainnav li.blog a").click(function () {
    $("#tagcloud").show();
});
$("ul.mainnav li a").not(blogLink).click(function () {
    $("#tagcloud").hide();
});
```

Give that one a try :)

And about that "use class not ID thing," that was before I saw what you were actually trying to do. You *should* be using ID if there's only one instance - sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Side note: The unique ID problem can be fixed by using a class rather than id for tagcloud. This, however, may not fix the main problem you're having.

Comment: Aha - gotcha! I was assuming that there was one #tagcloud, and he was just being redundant. Replacing #tagcloud with .tagcloud in that code makes it make a lot more sense to me. Yes, use classes :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your goal here without seeing some HTML as well, but just a couple things you could check first.

- $('ul.mainnav) ... You need to close that string up
- $(this).next("#tagcloud") ... You can simply use $("#tagcloud") since you should have unique IDs on the page.

If you post some more of the code that might help people.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the syntax errors already mentioned in this thread, you'll probably need to return false; on those link clicks, otherwise your action will occur, and the link will still head off to wherever.

Of course, this opens the door on the accessibility argument. I'd sooner get a working demo before worrying about that aspect, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have a go: your `click` handler on `li.blogcontent` is bubbling up to `ul.mainnav` and executing its `click` handler, too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.blogcontent').click(function(e) { 
        e.stopPropagation();   // Stop the bubbling up to its parent
        $("#tagcloud").show();
    });
    $('ul.mainnav').click(function() {
        $("#tagcloud").hide(); 
    });                            
});
</script>
```

or using event delegation and bubbling (which I haven't tested, but should be close):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.mainnav').click(function(e) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        if(target.hasClass('blogcontent')){
            $("#tagcloud").show();
        }
        else{
            $("#tagcloud").hide(); 
        }
    });                            
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The event bubbling up from the li element to the ul container is probably the problem. I'm a bit unfamiliar with jQuery but if it is passing straight DOM Events without modifying it (which I doubt it is since the author of jQuery is rather against modifying existing objects) then I would suggest against using only preventDefault() as it is not supported by *all* browsers. Should have a method in your toolbelt for stopping events and preventing bubbling e.g.

```
function stopEvent(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
   event.stopped = true;
}
```